# Count characters in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

is there a way to explicitly count characters in a pandas column for Strings and group them by their respective word?

```
df["text"]=[["Hello how are you?"],["I am fine"]]
Then the counter should be
df["count"]= [[0-4 6-8 10-12 14-16 17],[0 2-3 5-8]]
```

Comment: So the pandas column is a single string? Could you add a more meaningful example?

Comment: This is a task, not a question. What have you tried? At what point did your approach fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no pandas functionality for what you ask, but you can do:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["Hello how are you?"], ["I am fine"]], columns=['text'])


def extract_spans(m):
    """Convert span to required string representation"""
    start, end = m.span()
    return f'{start}-{end - 1}' if end - start > 1 else f'{start}'


# create count column
df['count'] = [' '.join([extract_spans(m) for m in re.finditer(r'([^\w\s_]|\w+)', v)]) for v in df['text'].tolist()]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                 text                   count
0  Hello how are you?  0-4 6-8 10-12 14-16 17
1           I am fine               0 2-3 5-8
```